# Is there a way to hide problem decorations for warning in explorer view of VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is the Problem decoration (error indicator) I am talking about in the explorer view

[image: problem decorator]

Now this decoratior/error occurs whenever there is a WARNING or an ERROR discovered by the linter, in my case ESLint

[image: linter error]

My question is I don't want it to show a decoration/error in the explorer view just for Warnings, I only want an indicator when there is an Error from the linter like this

[image: linter errors]

I have checked  and found this setting `"problems.decorations.enabled": true,` which seems to work for all WARNING/ERRORS. If I set it to `false` even ERRORs disappear.

How can I make it only show when I have an Error and not a Warning from the Linter?

Comment: Are you not using a `eslintrc.json` file or configuration file?

Comment: @soulshined i am using a eslint config file, that is working fine, its not about eslint though. I can turn off those warningin eslint fine, but I don't want to do that, i just want warnings not to show up in the `explorer` view, the problems tab is fine

Comment: I see. I could be wrong, but don't think this is possible at this time